# Import categories in magento through script

Tags: category, import, script

Hello I have just started to learn magento. Now I was trying to import category in magento through script.

my magento code looks like

```
<?php
    require_once 'businessclasses.php';
    define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    $count = 0;

    echo "<pre>";
    $data= new getCSV();
    $rows=$data->getRootCategories(); // Gets the list of root categories.

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo $categoryName = $row['us']; // Name of Category

        // Create category object
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setStoreId(1); // 'US-Store' store is assigned to this category

        $rootCategory['name'] = $categoryName;
        $rootCategory['path'] = "1/23/25"; // this is the catgeory path
        $rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
        $rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;
        $rootCategory['is_anchor'] = 1;
        $rootCategory['thumbnail'] = $row['catimg'].'.jpg';
        $category->addData($rootCategory);

        try {
            $category->save();
            echo $rootCategoryId = $category->getId();
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Now the category is importing successfully but image is not setting up there. It is not displaying category image there.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I got my mistake.

```
$category->setStoreId(0); // <-- I was giving this Store ID wrong.
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like URapidflow, its much easier and has all the functionality built in for importing, also Magmi is useful tool to check and its free.

Comment: As a respond to this: Plug of our recently opensource module. Ho_Import: https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import